# In Unix ,If we list the no of files in a directory . if no file is found how to get only the output rather than the error message

Tags: bash, shell

```
/u/this/bin: ls /u/spols/30/myfile*|wc -l 
ls: cannot access '/u/spols/30/myfile*' : No Such File or directory
0
/u/this/bin:
```

In the above snippet I am trying to list the files and get the count of it.
If file is available it gives me the count alone.
But if the files are not available, it gives me the count and also the error message saying the file or directories not available.

So how can i list and get the count as zero without getting the error message? Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should execute the command on this way:

```
ls /u/spols/30/myfile* 2>/dev/null|wc -l
```

The idea is to redirect the STDERR (where the message is sent) to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

You may ignore error messages produced by `ls` command.
The code below redirects standard error stream of `ls` command to `/dev/null`.

```
ls /u/spols/30/myfile* 2>/dev/null | wc -l
```